# Running Cypress with Git Hub Actions

Tags: cypress

I want to run Cypress tests on Git Hub action. The GH page is enabled and the workflow seems to be passed:

[image]

But when I click Actions I should see the workflows, instead, it shows "There are no workflows run yet:

[image]

These are the files/folders I pushed to Git Hub:

[image]

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "customer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test:chrome": "cypress run --browser chrome",
    "combine:report":"mochawesome-merge ./mochawesome-report/*.json -o index.json",
    "generate:report": "merge index.json --reportDir public --assetsDir public/assets --reportPageTitle index.html"
  },
  "author": "ingridd",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^7.0.4",
    "cypress": "^6.4.0",
    "cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1",
    "cypress-wait-until": "^1.7.1",
    "mochawesome": "6.2.2",
    "mochawesome-merge": "4.2.0",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "5.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress-enter-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "cypress-get-table": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

And the cypress.json:

```
{"pageLoadTimeout": 900000,
    "includeShadowDom": true,
    "modifyObstructiveCode":false,
    "responseTimeout": 120000,
     "chromeWebSecurity":false,
     "numTestKeptInMemory":0,
     "waitForAnimations": true,
     "defaultCommandTimeout":100000,
     "reporter": "mochawesome",
     "reporterOptions":{
       "overwrite":false,
       "html":false,
       "json":true
     }
        }
```

On the/.github/workflows I uploaded the cypress-report.yml

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'

jobs:
  cypress-test:
    name: Run on Chrome 89
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    container: cypress/browsers:node14.16.0-chrome89-ff86
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install cypress and verify
        run: |
          npm ci
          $(npm bin)/cypress verify
      - name: Run Cypress tests
        run: npm run test:chrome
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Copy test execution videos and screenshots
        run: |
          mkdir public
          cp -r cypress/videos public/videos
          cp -r cypress/screenshots public/screenshots
      - name: Merge test reports
        run: npm run combine:report

      - name: Generate HTML report
        run: npm run generate:report
      
      - name: Deploy report page to GitHub Page
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./docs
```

Any help on how can I run the workflows is appreciated.

Comment: Your workflow file says only pushes to master should get built - is that the branch you're working on? Can you share the repo?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I am working on the master. Unfortunately, I can not share the repo.

Comment: Please create another one to minimally recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your Cypress version not stable I guess. You can fix your version and you should try again. Sometimes It can brake your build chain.

Answer (score 1):

I did a small change on the .yml file. Before it was selected 'Master' branch to push new commit to, but what I have is 'Main' branch. I also added the line `workflow_dispatch:` to manually running the workflow. Now the workflow is running.